# How to store files in H2 database - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, h2, file-storage

**Question**

How do I store entire files in my H2 database and retrieve them using JDBC?

---

**Some Background**

I have some text files that I have as templates for various documents that will be generated in my Spring Boot app. Currently, I have my text files stored in my local file system on my PC, but that is not a long term solution. I need to somehow store them in the database and provide the necessary code for the JDBC for the retrieval of the files.

Are there any technologies/libraries out there that would help me with this? If so, please link me to them and provide an example of how to do it in Spring Boot.

---

**Note:** It is a new requirement given to me that the text files should be stored in the database, and not the file system.

Comment: You can use a blob. Do you use JDBC with JdbcTemplate or JPA?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I use JDBCTemplate for JDBC operations. Please tell me what you mean by a blob by providing some links/examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a BLOB column in your database table.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, document BLOB);
```

BLOB stands for Binary Large Object.
http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#blob_type

To store it with JdbcTemplate you have to create a ByteArrayInputStream

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(document);
preparedStatement.setBlob(3, inputStream);
```

Please find more examples here:
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data-access-with-jdbc/jdbc-template-with-clob-blob.html

Comment: Reading the first link you provided, I think that using BLOB is not optimal for my case. Instead, I think I should use CLOB. It looks like the better option.

Comment: This does not matter.